# How to render a background image correctly?

Tags: rendering

I have followed this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ua7K4HvbfzA

And everything looks great in rendered view. But when I rendered image, it rendered the object first but put the background image in front of the object in the end. So what I could see after rendered image was the background image. Does anyone know what I ignored or what happened?

Answer (score 1):

[image]My guess would be that You missed to check the "transparent" checkbox under "film" in the "render" tab. Furthermore, You, perhaps, have switched the inputs in the "alpha over" node. See image to find critical settings marked with red circles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have solved the problem accidentally... I just reconnect the two connection to "alpha over". I didn't know why but it solved.  So I wonder does it matter which connect first? Or do you know what happened? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes! If you switch the two inputs in the alpha over node, it will put the background on top of the render, instead of the render on top of the background!

Answer (score 0):

1 Load your image as a texture

2 Check **Horizon** in the texture tab

[image: Settings]

3 In the **World** settings check **Paper Sky**

4 Press F12

Done

**OR**

Import your image as a plane (the add-on is included). Scale it, **proportions kept**, so that it's a bit bigger than the lens area. Put the plane scaled **behind** your object(s). Press F12 to render. This way is better in that the image is not stretched on a sphere as it is in the first case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder to know what you recommended--import image as a plane. But I didn't see it in the add-on. Can you tell me the whole name of it? Sorry for asking such a simple question... :)

Comment: In the add on tab search for Import Images as Planes.