# Background Green Screen Refuses to Render

Tags: rendering, image

I tried a few threads already on Blender Stack Exchange:

[How to render a background image in 2.8?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154792/how-to-render-a-background-image-in-2-8)

[How to render a background image correctly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116452/how-to-render-a-background-image-correctly)

[why the background image I add not show in render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161052/why-the-background-image-i-add-not-show-in-render)

I'm using '**Images as Background**' add-on. I've tried the 'Film' 'Transparent' recommendation. The render icon is on in the outliner. I've messed with the nodes all day. Nothing seems to be working.

I made an animation in 2.79, and I opened the file in 2.83,(I checked the box to not load the UI thing) so maybe a few bugs from the old one got into the this file because I tried loading up a new 2.83 file and the background rendered just fine with no modifications.

I am using HitFilm 3 Express as my video editing program, I am more comfortable with it than Blender's internal video editing software. So I'm rendering out a greenscreen for the program to use.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why this green backdrop? Suggest render your object (foreground) with transparent background enabled.

Comment: That would be another option, yes. This option was linked to having a background image actually render with another project of mine, however transparency would be better.

Comment: That's the only option for a nice comp, ideally rendered to openexr: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106670/compositors-corner-pin-node-does-something-odd-to-input-image/106671#106671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So immediately after writing this post, I had a realization. Sometimes objects don't show up in the 3D viewer, so you increase the distance you can see by hitting 'N' and going to 'View'. However I can already see it in the 3D Viewer, but then I thought that there were different properties set to the camera than the 3D Viewport.

There is a post that deals with this, which makes my post a duplicate.
[How do I increase the render distance?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-do-i-increase-the-render-distance)

[image]